# QObject:Cannot create children for a parent that is in different thread.Parent is QTextDocument,parent's thread is QThread,current thread is QThread

Tags: python, multithreading, pyside, python-multithreading

I am new to python threading and Pyside. I am working on making a communication between two computers but could not create a thread on receiving side
Here is server code

```
from PySide import QtCore, QtGui
import sys
import receiver
import os
from socket import *
import thread

class mainWindow(QtGui.QMainWindow, receiver.Ui_MainWindow):
def __init__(self):
    super(self.__class__,self).__init__()
    self.setupUi(self)
    self.show()
    thread.start_new_thread(self.listener,())

def listener(self):
    host = ""
    port = 13000
    buf = 1024
    addr = (host, port)
    UDPSock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM)
    UDPSock.bind(addr)
    (data, addr) = UDPSock.recvfrom(buf)    
    self.textEdit.setText(data)
    UDPSock.close()

def main():
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    mainWin = mainWindow()
    mainWin.show()
    app.exec_() 


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

When I send any message from client, program crashes.

Thread is working perfectly on client side.
Here is a client code

```
from PySide import QtCore, QtGui
import sys
import main
import os
from socket import *
import thread

class mainWindow(QtGui.QMainWindow, main.Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(self.__class__,self).__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.show()
        self.sendButton.clicked.connect(self.clientProcess)

    def clientProcess(self):
        thread.start_new_thread(self.makeClient,())

    def makeClient(self):
        host = "192.168.43.143"
        port = 13000
        addr = (host, port)
        UDPSock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM)
        data = "Successfully Completed"
        UDPSock.sendto(data, addr)
        UDPSock.close()

def main():
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    mainWin = mainWindow()
    mainWin.show()
    app.exec_()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

In your code, you should only create a thread for the client, not the server.  For the server, simply create a while loop within the "listener" method to wait for "data" as such:

```
while 1:
    (data, addr) = UDPSock.recvfrom(buf)
    if data:
        self.textEdit.setText(data)
        UDPSock.close()
        break
    else:
        pass
```

Also, rather than having the two MainWindow instances inherit from each other, simply pass the client window instance to the server.

Here is a working version (I tested it on Python 3.x and then adapted it back to Python 2.x which I assumed you were using):

main.py:

```
from PySide import QtCore, QtGui
import sys
import receiver
import os
from socket import *
import thread

class mainWindow(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, receive_obj):
        super(self.__class__,self).__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.show()
        threadstart_new_thread(receive_obj.makeClient,())
        self.listener()

    def listener(self):
        host = ""
        port = 13000
        buf = 1024
        addr = (host, port)
        UDPSock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM)
        UDPSock.bind(addr)
        while 1:
            (data, addr) = UDPSock.recvfrom(buf)
            if data:
                self.textEdit.setText(data)
                UDPSock.close()
                break
            else:
                pass

def main():
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    mainWin2 = receiver.mainWindow()
    mainWin1 = mainWindow(mainWin2)
    mainWin2.show()
    mainWin1.show()
    app.exec_()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

receiver.py:

```
from PySide import QtCore, QtGui
import sys
import os
from socket import *
import socket
import thread

def runClient(win):
    win.makeClient()


class mainWindow(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(self.__class__,self).__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.show()

    def clientProcess(self):
        thread.start_new_thread(self.makeClient,())

    def makeClient(self):
        host = "192.168.43.143"
        port = 13000
        addr = (host, port)
        UDPSock = socket.socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM)
        data = "Successfully Completed"
        UDPSock.sendto(data, addr)
        UDPSock.close()


def main():
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    mainWin = mainWindow()
    mainWin.show()
    app.exec_()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Let me know if this doesn't work for you; like I said, it worked on 3.x but I had to adapt it for 2.x and could not test it.

Thanks!